# Python Beautifulsoup / Requests text from span

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to extract text using beautifulsoup or requests from this facebook page https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/item/1612977352197759/

the text is the item description, the text before the map:
[image: Element i want to extract]
this is what i've tried till now but not working :

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from lxml import html

opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
opt.add_argument("start-maximized")
# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 2,
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 2,
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 2,
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
    })
global driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)


driver.get('https://www.google.com')

page = requests.get('https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/item/1612977352197759/?ref=messenger_banner')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
print(tree)
link = tree.xpath("//span[contains(string(),'hello')]")
print(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
page = requests.get('https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/item/1612977352197759/?ref=messenger_banner')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')
span = soup.find("span",string=re.compile(".*hello.*"))
print(span)
```

Do let me know if this works.

Comment: @Mooncraster thank you for your answer, print(span) output : None

Comment: I'll check this in a while. Basically it means that it could not find the `span` element. For testing, what I would have done is 1. Print the `page.text` variable, and check if it actually has that span. 2. If it doesn't then it's some issue with authentication maybe?, If it does have the element, then we're just not able to find it. Go to 3 then. 3. There is a problem with `soup.find`. Check if this works : `soup.find('span',string="hello how are you doing 3")`. This should work. If this too doesn't work, let me know. If it works there is some problem with the regular expression.

Comment: i tried them all, and the last one gave me output : None . i'm still stuck :(

Comment: @AnnahLairy I tried to open the link, and I can not find any span that contains the words you mentioned. The marketplace you might be trying to open doesn't open the same for me (India). So the content you might be trying to might be dynamic. `requests` can only show you the base HTML, and not the aftereffects of the dynamic changes made to the page.

Comment: I've tried to create a room [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/219115/bs4-requests), see if you can access it. Let's carry out the discussion there/